# convert unicodestring to string in xrad studio

Tags: c++, string, c++builder, unicode-string

I have a problem in "Rad Studio 10 Seattle" where I am trying to get text input from a `TEdit` object and I get a errormessage saying

> E2034 Cannot convert 'UnicodeString' to 'string'

My code is as follows:

```
this->shopVar->addDog(edName->Text, StrToInt(edAge->Text), "male", "dogspecial");
```

This function `addDog` takes `(string, int, string, string)`
When I try to send the text from the `TEdit` object with `edName->Text` I get the errormessage mentioned earlier.

My question is as follows, can i make a convertion on `edName` from unicodestring to string or do I have to change the datatype of my parameterlist? If so, how do I do it?
I have been searching for this issue but have not found anything that is similar to my problem.

Comment: *I have been searching for this issue but have not found anything that is similar to my problem.* -- ??? Converting between string types is an often asked question here.  Maybe not C++ Builder string types, but string types nonetheless (Unicode to char-based, char-based to Unicode, char-based to wide char-based, LPCSTR, LPCTSTR, etc. etc.).  Your Builder string type "UnicodeString" is probably just their way of saying the word "Unicode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `UnicodeString` data to Ansi first, then pass that instead.  The easiest way is to assign the `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString` (or derivative) first, and then use its `c_str()` method to get a `char*` pointer, which `std::string` will accept:

```
this->shopVar->addDog(AnsiString(edName->Text).c_str(), ...);
```

*If possible*, maybe consider rewriting your `shopVar` class to use `std::wstring` instead, then you can remove the Ansi conversion:

```
this->shopVar->addDog(edName->Text.c_str(), StrToInt(edAge->Text), L"male", L"dogspecial");
```