# How to convert AnsiString to std::string in C++ Builder?

Tags: string, text, casting, edit, c++builder

I would like to ask how can I get a text input from `TEdit` control and cast it to `std::string` (not `AnsiString`).

For example, if I have a `TEdit` control with the name `User`, I get the text from it with the `User->Text` command.  What I want to do is to assign that value to a `std::string`, for example `string my_str = User->Text;`.

I would like to ask, how can I do this in C++ Builder? Is there some sort of a `ToString()` method or sort of, because I was not able to find one.

Comment: Probably using User->Text.c_str(), which IIRC both AnsiString and UnicodeString should have. Which version are you using?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.AnsiStringT.c_str

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert unicodestring to string in xrad studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661481/convert-unicodestring-to-string-in-xrad-studio)

Answer (score 3):

In C++Builder 2007 and earlier, `TEdit::Text` is an 8-bit `AnsiString` in the user's default ANSI locale.  It is very straight forward to convert an `AnsiString` to a `std::string` - just use the `AnsiString::c_str()` method to get a null-terminated `char*` pointer to the `AnsiString` data, and then you can assign that to the `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
std::string my_str = User->Text.c_str();
/* or:
System::AnsiSystem text = User->Text;
std::string my_str(text.c_str(), text.Length());
*/
```

If you want the `std::string` data to be in another character encoding, such as UTF-8, then you will have to convert the `AnsiString` data accordingly, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()`/`WideCharToMultiByte()`, `UTF8Encode()`, etc, before assigning it to the `std::string`.

---

In C++Builder 2009 and later, `TEdit::Text` is a 16-bit `UnicodeString` in UTF-16 format.  The easiest way to convert a `UnicodeString` to a `std::string` is to first convert to an `AnsiStringT<CP>` (where `CP` is the desired ANSI codepage - `AnsiString` uses `CP=0`, `UTF8String` uses `CP=65001`, etc), and then convert that to `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
std::string my_str = AnsiString(User->Text).c_str(); // or UTF8String, etc...
/* or:
System::AnsiString text = User->Text; // or UTF8String, etc...
std::string my_str(text.c_str(), text.Length());
*/
```

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can convert the `UnicodeString` to a `std::wstring` first, and then use [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert), eg:

```cpp
#include <locale>

std::wstring my_wstr = User->Text.c_str();
/* or:
System::UnicodeString text = User->Text;
std::wstring my_wstr(text.c_str(), text.Length());
*/

// System::Char may be either wchar_t or char16_t, depending
// on which platform you are compiling for...
std::string my_str = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<System::Char>>{}.to_bytes(my_wstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of those to migrate from Borland to Embarcadero Rio. So I created a method to do it.

```
#include <cwchar.h>   //std::wcslen

char* __fastcall AnsiOf(wchar_t* w)
{
 static char c[STR_CONV_BUF_SIZE];
 memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));
 WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, w, std::wcslen(w), c, STR_CONV_BUF_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
 return c;
}

std::string my_str = AnsiOf((User->Text).c_str());
```